# BCD Subtraction of two negative numbers?

Tags: binary

I just learned how to subtract a smaller BCD number from a large number and vice versa. For example; I can compute **+27+(-14)** ,  **+14+-(27)**. Now I am confused as to how to do **(-27)+(-14)**. Can somene please help. I'm using 10's complement.

Comment: Explain BCD = Binary Coded Decimal

Answer (score 0):

Well, $(-27)+(-14)=-(27+14)$.